# Replace values in one column by taking values from another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

After asking one question this morning, now I would like to ask another way to do the replacement, since I am waiting my teacher confirm about the species name.

I have a dataframe like this (The real `df` resulted by removing duplicated rows)

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("a" , "b", "c", "a"),
                 name2 = c("x", NA, NA, NA),
                 name3 = c(NA, "b1", "c1", NA),
                 name4 = c("x", "b1", "c1", "a"))

  name1 name2 name3 name4
1     a     x  <NA>     x
2     b  <NA>    b1    b1
3     c  <NA>    c1    c1
4     a  <NA>  <NA>     a
```

Can we replace `a` by `x` by calling if the value in `name4` column match with `name1` column?

I do not want to use and assign `x` directly here since my data is supposed to have many cases like this. Any suggestions for me, please? (using base-R also fine for me since I would love to learn more)

Desired output

```
  name1 name2 name3 name4
1     a     x  <NA>     x
2     b  <NA>    b1    b1
3     c  <NA>    c1    c1
4     a  <NA>  <NA>     x
```

My explanation for the table and my expectation:

I have 3 columns name1, name2, name3 (after removing duplicated rows). Name4 column is the final column that contains value that I want from 3 previous columns. The value in name2 column is the my first priority to use, then value in name3.

In my fourth row, since NA value appears in name2 column, then I took an "a" from name1 column. I am thinking that whether can I replace a by x without assigning x i.e. if value (i.e. a) in name4 == value (i.e. a) in name1, then the a in name4 replaced by x in name2 or 4.

Comment: Does the "x" you don't want to be explicitly used come from the name2 column in the row where name1 has an "a"? I don't understand what would you like to do

Comment: Sorry I think i am going to confuse people, I gonna close and ask another one more clear.

Comment: You should not delete a question where many users already spent time to give you an answer. Instead you should improve your question by editing it.

Comment: You still did not answer the question in the comments. *Where* does the `x` value come from (if it is not supposed to be hardcoded)? What logic should the replacement value follow?

Comment: so lets say from the beginning, I have 3 columns name1, name2, name3 (after removing duplicated rows). Name4 column is the final column that contains value that I want from 3 previous columns. The value in name2 column is the my first priority to use, then value in name3

Comment: In my fourth row, since NA value appears in name2 column, then I took an "a" from name1 column. I am thinking that whether can I replace a by x without assigning x i.e. if value (i.e.  a) in name4 == value  (i.e. a) in name1, then the a in name4 replaced by x in name2 or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `name1` and if `name1` and `name4` are equal replace the `name4` value with 1st non-NA value available.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  mutate(name4 = ifelse(name1 == name4, na.omit(unlist(cur_data()))[1], name4)) %>%
  ungroup

# name1 name2 name3 name4
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     x     NA    x    
#2 b     NA    b1    b1   
#3 c     NA    c1    c1   
#4 a     NA    NA    x
```

Comment: the code worked well for my reproducible data, but it wont work for my data :(. the value kept the same after i run the code

Comment: Did you assign the the output back to the dataframe? `df <- df %>% group_by(name1) ...` ?

Comment: it worked well man. However, what if I have one more column between name1 and name2 column. Since if I have that column, the code would not work.

Comment: If you want to select values only from specific column you can change `na.omit(unlist(cur_data()))[1]` to `na.omit(unlist(select(cur_data(), name1, name2)))[1]`

Comment: I just realized that I also need name3 column work as name2 column.  If name1 == name 4, then take value from name3 to replace for the value in name4 (as the same above). But now name1 will contain some NA value. I tried again above code but it looked weird now. Can u look at that please

Answer (score 4):

Your criteria to define `name4` as I understand it is:

1. Use `name2` from the same row if available
2. Use `name3` from the same row if available
3. Leave it missing (for now)
4. Fill missing `name4` values with `name4` values from previous rows that share the same `name1` value.

If you want a tidyverse-based solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(name1 = c("a" , "b", "c", "a"),
                 name2 = c("x", NA, NA, NA),
                 name3 = c(NA, "b1", "c1", NA))

result <- df %>% 
  mutate(name4 = case_when(
    #!is.na(name4) ~ name4, # when name4 is not missing, use it? If you like...
    !is.na(name2) ~ name2, # when name2 is not missing, use it
    !is.na(name3) ~ name3, # when name3 is not missing, use it
    TRUE ~ NA_character_   # leave a NA for now otherwise
  )) %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  fill(name4, .direction = c("down")) %>% # Fill each group looking at the previous non-missing row.
  ungroup()
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  name1 name2 name3 name4
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     x     NA    x    
2 b     NA    b1    b1   
3 c     NA    c1    c1   
4 a     NA    NA    x
```

Note that `fill` can fill in several directions, you could use "downup" if you want to first fill from top to bottom and then bottom to top.

Comment: thank you so much, much understandable. However, I realized that since name4 column already existed, then NA values will be given even for the name that I want to remain in name4 column.

Comment: The main issue we all are having is to understand what are your requirements, your criteria, what is that you want to do. The best you can do is to improve your question and clarify what you need to do. I tried to explain the requirements I understood from your question in my answer, but they were not correct. Could you copy my initial paragraph/list about the criteria and change it so it does what you expect (how to handle the existing name4 column)? Then it should be much easier for us to help you find the solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df[which(df$name1==df$name4), "name4"] <- "x"
```

Basically this means subsetting your dataframe selecting rows, in which `name1 == name4`, and `name4` column, then changing these values to "x"

Comment: Or similarly: `df$name4[df$name1 == df$name4] <- "x"` (just a matter of taste)

Comment: yes, but here we are calling exact the x. I dont want to use it here. Since what if I have many cases.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Suggested solution leads to the result you mentioned

Comment: I already updated  my comment above, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Base R `ifelse` solution:

```
df$name4 <- ifelse(df$name1 == df$name4, "x", df$name4)
```

Based on your update, using `dplyr`'s `first`:

```
library(dplyr)

df$name4 <- ifelse(df$name1 == df$name4, first(df$name4), df$name4)
```

This does the following:

- Checks to see if name1 is equal to name 4
- If name1 is equal to name4, it replaces the value of name4 with the first value occurring for name4.

Result:

```
  name1 name2 name3 name4
1     a     x  <NA>     x
2     b  <NA>    b1    b1
3     c  <NA>    c1    c1
4     a  <NA>  <NA>     x
```

Comment: I tried it but it wouldnt work since it automatically raised many duplicated rows in name4 column for my real data with name1 based value (i.e. a)